# Magento API V2 - Filtering on fields that have never been set for a product

Tags: magento, filter, magento-1.9, soap-client, complextype

How do I search for products where the field has never been set?

I'm attempting to filter products using the following code:

```
$filters = array(
    "filter" =>
        array(
            array("key" => "sku", "value" => "examplesku123")
        ),
    "complex_filter" => array(
        array(
            "key" => "barcode",
            "value" => array(
                "key" => "null",
                "value" => ""
            )
    )
);
$result = $client->catalogProductList($session, $filters);

 print "<pre>";
 print_r($result);
 print "</pre>";
```

The example product has no value set in the barcode field within Magento.  However, when I run this code, it's not bringing the product back.

I've tried changing the complex filter to "eq", moving it into the normal filters, even setting the value to "NO FIELD" but it's not showing anything.

I don't have access to the database so I cannot show you what it looks like in the back end.  However, I can see within the admin panel that there's nothing in the barcode field.

I've managed to get this code to work for other SKUs so I can only assume it's not finding this product as the product has never had anything set for it (and presumably the field is not 'available' and thus not NULL).

Answer (score 0):

maybe your complex filter does not work because you forgot to remove regular filter?

like this

```
$filters = array(
    "complex_filter" => array(
        array(
            "key" => "barcode",
            "value" => array(
                "key" => "null",
                "value" => ""
            )
        )
    )
);
$result = $client->catalogProductList($session, $filters);
```

also make sure "barcode" is a valid attribute code.

Comment: I'm only showing the normal filter in this case as an example.  That product has no barcode associated to it, so if I remove the normal filter, I expect to see that SKU come back in the result set.  However, it doesn't.  Also the barcode is a valid attribute code :)